# How to specify a default value for a field of a LinqToSQL model?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, database-design

I use Visual Studio data classes designer to draw the model first and generate the database then. I want a field (boolean in the class, int in the table) to be non-nullable but optional to specify. How do I specify a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the field of interest in the dbml and select Properties and toggle Auto Generated Value.  This will address the case when the created SQL field has a default value, e.g., "created DATETIME DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE()) NOT NULL".

[image]

You can set the DEFAULT value using ALTER.  How to do it graphically though I'm not certain.

Comment: This isn't quite the right answer. This does give you a default value, but ONLY that default value. You can't then come in and set that value to anything else - LINQtoSQL throws an error. That's generally not the intended goal with a default value column (one with a DEFAULT constraint added on the table).